# Mysql match against not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I want sort the mysql result with relevance.

The workflow is as follows:

I search resume with keywords `Java, Php`

And write query to calculate relevance.

```
$keyStr="Java PHP";
```

`res_id` and `res_keyskills` in **Resumes** table loook like

```
1   Java,PHP
2   PHP,Java
3   Javascript, Java
4   Java
5   PHP
6   Python
7   PHP, C
```

etc

```
SELECT *, match(res_keyskills) against ('".$keyStr."') AS relevance FROM Resumes
```

Currently I am getting relevance greater than 0 for `res_id`  **1, 3, 4**

But the expected result is relevance greater than 0 for `res_id` **1,2 3, 4,5,7**

Since the `$keyStr` is starts with `Java`, the `relevance` is set to the `res_keyskills` which are starts with `Java`.

But I need to set the `relevance` for `res_keyskills`  having `Java or Php`.

**For this what change should I do in my query or should I change the input string format(currently seperated by space)**

Comment: SELECT *, contains(res_keyskills) against ('".$keyStr."') AS relevance FROM Resumes  try this.

Comment: Why do you store the skills as continuous text anyway? With a relational database one would expect a skill table and a bridge table linking res and skill. Then you could simply count where skill in ('Java', 'PHP').

Comment: Split the search keyword on the basis of space, then search in db using like clause. After split, you have two keyword "Java" & "php". Then search in your database using `select * from <tablename> where res_keyskills like '%java%' or '%php%'`

Comment: @Learner, `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') against ('Java Php') AS relevance FROM jp_resumes `  and my query is    `SELECT *, contains(res_keyskills) against ('Java Php') AS relevance FROM jp_resumes`

Comment: Fulltext search does its searching for the words having 4 character lengths minimum

Comment: @Dipanwita Kundu: `like '%java%'` gives a false positive on 'JavaScript'.

Comment: @Learner, Please find the use & syntax of `Contains`:  https://blog.udemy.com/sql-contains/

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I don't understand your comment, but as per his requirement, he wants to show the "JavaScript" also.& Mysql is case insensitive, so it it will return "JavaScript" also.

Comment: @Dipanwita Kundu: Java and JavaScript are two different languages. In the sample there is just one entry 'Javascript, Java', which is a match (on 'Java'). If there where another entry, say,'Javascript, C', then this should certainly be no match, because it contains neither Java nor PHP. (And just imgine the matches you'd get for '%c%'; it would return all languages that happen to contain a 'c'.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, please check his question, Here is his requirement `But the expected result is relevance greater than 0 for res_id 1,2 3, 4,5,7` & 4th is `Java`

Comment: @Dipanwita Kundu: Yes, record 4 is a match, because the skill is Java and they are looking for Java (and PHP). They are not looking for JavaScript.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, ok got your point. Then instead of `like` use `match-aganist ` or `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: I am trying to set relevance for each result depending upon the percentage of matching...And still not get correct result

Comment: "I want sort the mysql result with relevance": So you want to see all matches (records 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7), but records 1 and 2 should come first, because they match both skills, whereas the others only match one each. Correct?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, Yes..

Comment: It should work as you expect it. Maybe it's a problem in your version of MySQL. See the rextester I set up: http://rextester.com/GICXAV72717. It works both on 'Java,PHP' and 'PHP,JAVA'. However, as text matching is made to deal with natural text, there are issues. `MATCH AGAINST ('C')` for instance does not work. Maybe because a letter is not considered a word.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying `no operator` in your query. When you do that you're saying:

> Find rows that contain at least one of the two words.

Instead try to specify `+` operator and try. Which means:

> Find rows that contain the `first word`, but rank rows higher if they also contain `second word`.

Something like:

```
SELECT *, match(res_keyskills) against ('+".$keyStr."') AS relevance FROM Resumes
```

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)